# Ordering list of String trough other list of String

Tags: list, haskell

I have two lists `["a","b","c","d"]` and `["b","d","a","c"]`

How can I make a function that orders the first list with the same order of the second one?

In this example something like this:

```
> ord ["a","b","c","d"] ["b","d","a","c"] 
["b","d","a","c"]
```

all the function I make give me an incomplete list:

```
ord :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
ord [] _ = []
ord (h:t) (x:xs) | (h==x) = h:(ord t xs)
                 | otherwise = ord t (x:xs)
```

This is only an example; I can't simply present the second list.

Comment: What should `ord ["a", "b", "not in second list"] ["b", "a", "not in first list"]` be?

Comment: i can assure you that it won't happen, cause the data that the function receives is controlled

Comment: The explanation of this problem is unclear. Does the output for `[a, b, a, b] [b, a]` be `[b, b, a, a]`?

Comment: no it's not homework. the lists that the function receives are controlled so the 1st list won't have repeated elems.

Comment: @Ferreira58: Then why can't you just return the second list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that builds the result by grouping each string in the first list by the order in the second (I also renamed `ord` to `orderThese`):

```hs
orderThese :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] 
orderThese _ [] = []
orderThese as (b:bs) = filter (\x -> x == b) as ++ orderThese as bs
```

As an example, `orderThese ["a", "c", "a", "b"] ["b", "a", "c"]` returns `["b","a","a","c"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (elemIndex, sortBy)

ord :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
ord listToSort desiredOrder = sortBy (compare `on` (`elemIndex` desiredOrder)) listToSort
```

I would suggest that

- you give the function a different name, as there is a function called `ord` in `Data.Char`; and
- you swap the order of the parameters, as it seems more likely that you would want to partially apply the function with a `desiredOrder` than with a `listToSort`.